# Is it possible to have enumeration values as private static final constants in Java?

Tags: java, enums, constants

Is it possible to have enumeration values as private static final constants in Java?

I am currently writing an IssueTest class for the Issue class. In the Issue class, I have an inner enumeration for the type of Issue, which may be a bug or enhancement.

```
public enum IssueType {
        ENHANCEMENT,
        BUG;
}
```

In one of the constructors for an Issue, one of the parameters is the IssueType.

```
public Issue(IssueType type, String state, String summary) {

}
```

I am trying to write a case to test this constructor. In my test class, I have tried to create a constant for the IssueTypes like so

```
private static final IssueType TYPE_BUG = BUG;  
private static final IssueType TYPE_ENHANCEMENT = ENHANCEMENT;
```

But these lines are creating compiler errors. I am not sure how to use an IssueType constant in my test class to test the constructors. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably want that to be a `public static enum`.  Then in the test class, you can write `YourClass.IssueType.ENHANCEMENT`.  No point in making an extra variable for that.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Aren't enums implicitly static?

Comment: You can create your object like `new Issue(IssueType.BUG, "OPEN", "summary");`. If I were you I wouldn't bother creating a variable to store the enum value. The enum is pretty readable and `IssueType.BUG` tells exactly what it is.

Comment: Yes, nested enum types are [implicitly static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9). And if the OP dislikes `IssueType.BUG` he can just statically import the `Issue.IssueType.*` into the test class.

Comment: You forget to tell us what the compiler error was, but you need `IssueType TYPE_BUG = IssueType.BUG`. But you don't actually need these static finals at all. Just use the appropriate qualifed enum values. You're really just obfuscating your code with this doubletalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said before, you should not create redundant `static final` members inside your test, but if you insist you can. If done correctly, there should not be any compiler error.

My little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) shows how to do both, using redundant static fields and elegantly using the enumeration constants directly:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60556923;

public class Issue {
  public enum IssueType {
    ENHANCEMENT,
    BUG
  }

  public Issue(IssueType type, String state, String summary) {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60482676;

import de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60556923.Issue.IssueType;
import org.junit.Test;

import static de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60556923.Issue.IssueType.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class IssueTest {
  // Seriously?! Nah, rather not.
  private static final IssueType TYPE_BUG = BUG;
  private static final IssueType TYPE_ENHANCEMENT = ENHANCEMENT;

  @Test
  public void testUsingStaticFinal() {
    // Does this make anything better or just obfuscate and complicate the test?
    assertEquals("BUG", TYPE_BUG.toString());
    assertEquals("ENHANCEMENT", TYPE_ENHANCEMENT.toString());
  }

  @Test
  public void testUsingEnumDirectly() {
    assertEquals("BUG", BUG.toString());
    assertEquals("ENHANCEMENT", ENHANCEMENT.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: One would hope that the OP's tests are doing more than just testing the platform like these ones.

Comment: Of course. He said he gets compile errors when using the `static IssueType` members. I am just showing that (a) there is no compile error when done correctly and (b) using those redundant static members is completely unnecessary. This is why it is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What else should I test if he is not disclosing any more details about the class under test?

Comment: Sure, of course ,I upvoted your answer, just a side comment.

Comment: Not that it is so important, but nobody has cast any votes on my answer yet. 

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful! Sorry for the dumb question, I am a beginner.